# How define total amounts showed in transactions mails

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

We have all the prices setup including VAT.

Right now in the transactional Mails we get the following output:

```
Subtotal            USD 50.00
Shipping & Handling USD  5.00
Total (exkl. VAT)   USD 55.00
VAT                 USD  0.00
Total (incl. VAT)   USD 55.00
```

But we would like to have:

```
Subtotal            USD 50.00
Shipping & Handling USD  5.00
Total (inkl. VAT)   USD 55.00
```

How can we achieve that?

Thanks
Aldo